# Sharing data thru several controllers. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, repository, ninject

If I have two controllers:

```
public class PrimaryController : Controller
{
    private IRepository<Primaries> repository;

    public PrimaryController(IRepository<Primaries> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // CRUD operations
}
```

and

```
public class AuxiliaryController : Controller
{
    private IRepository<Primaries> repository;

    public AuxiliaryController(IRepository<Primaries> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // CRUD operations
    public ActionResult CreateSomethingAuxiliary(Guid id, AuxiliaryThing auxiliary)
    {
        var a = repository.Get(id);
        a.Auxiliaries.Add(auxiliary);
        repository.Save(a);

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Primary", new { id = id });
    }
}
```

and *DI* is implemented like (code is from a `Ninject` module)

```
this.Bind<ISessionFactory>()
    .ToMethod(c => new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory())
    .InSingletonScope();

this.Bind<ISession>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.TryGet<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
    .InRequestScope();

this.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

will this work properly? I mean will controllers use the same repository instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - yes! Code will use same **implementation** for all controllers unless you explicitly configure otherwise, using `When...` methods.

If you want to reuse not implementation, but **same instance of object**, you could configure that using methods like `InScope`, `InRequestScope`, `InSingletonScope` as you already do for ISession and ISessionFactory.

From documentation:

```
// Summary:
//     Indicates that instances activated via the binding should be re-used within
//     the same HTTP request.
IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> InRequestScope();


//
// Summary:
//     Indicates that only a single instance of the binding should be created, and
//     then should be re-used for all subsequent requests.
IBindingNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> InSingletonScope();
```

Using `Repository` in singleton is not a good Idea. I use `InRequestScope` to make one  instance serve just one request. If using entity framework, you could check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392) for details

Comment: Yes I need the same instance. So should I use `InSingletonScope`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the default scope in ninject works (I'm not a ninject user).

It will however work if you specify `InRequestScope` on the  repository mapping.

```
this.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .To(typeof(Repository<>))
    .InRequestScope();
```

Singleton scope will work as long as the connection to the database is not closed. Your application will stop work when it does since all requests would still try to use the same repository object.

That's why Request scope is better. If the repos fail, it will only fail for one request (unless it's a problem with the db).

I've written a set of best practices: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/inversion-of-control-containers-best-practices/